# Marvell network adapter driver PTP support

Tags: 20.04

Marvell Aqc113 network adapter driver doesn't support PTP timestamping mode

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ijjM.jpg)

[check PTP clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quYjp.jpg)